# Dictionaries and loops in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

**We have a group grade log:**

```
log = {

    'Alex': [3, 7, 11, 10, 8],

    'Ben': [6, 12, 4, 9, 9],

    'Сarla': [5, 10, 7, 5, 9]}
```

**Output "Best student X, he has the maximum score Y, minimum score Z"**

**Solution**

I have a dictionary, the first thing I decided to do was transform it and replace the values with new ones by hooking the maximum and minimum scores for each student. After that, in a loop I wanted to go through only the maximum scores of each student and find the maximum average and, using it, return the key in the dictionary that corresponds to the meaning. But an error occurs that I cannot figure out. After passing through the loop, the data is converted to int and it is impossible to work with them. What to do?

**Code**

```
log = {
    'Alex': [3, 7, 11, 10, 8],
    'Ben': [6, 12, 4, 9, 9],
    'Carla': [5, 10, 7, 5, 9]}

log.update({"Alex":[min(log["Alex"])] + [max(log["Alex"])],
                 "Ben":[min(log["Ben"])] + [max(log["Ben"])],
                 "Carla":[min(log["Carla"])] + [max(log["Carla"])]})

for i,j in log.values():
    print(max(i,j))
```

**Output**

```
3 11

4 12

5 10
```

Here is the problem, int object isn't itarible. I want to find the largest pair, that is **max(j)**, I have to go through, but then how can I return a pair of values at once, and not just the **max(j)**.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: How do you decide who is the best student? EDIT: I think you mean maximum of the average.

Comment: I guess it's Output "Best student Ben, he has the maximum score 12, minimum score 4", no?

Comment: So, you just wanna sort based on maximum score and output the respective student? What's the significance of minimum score?

Comment: Each student have two criteria's max and min. The student who have the biggest maximum score is the best. And for this student you could find the minimum

Comment: I think to sort by maximum, and then just find the minimum score for the best student and display

Comment: Leaving aside the broken indentation, the code does nothing of what you describe. It provides different output (namely only the second column) and does not result in an error. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit it is not 100% clear to me want you want to achieve - anyway, this is my try (using the minimum amount of Python notions and mantaining your code as much as possible):

```
log = {
    'Alex': [3, 7, 11, 10, 8],
    'Ben': [6, 12, 4, 9, 9],
    'Carla': [5, 10, 7, 5, 9]}

for key, vs in log.items():
    log.update({key: [[min(vs)] + [max(vs)]]})

#log.update({"Alex":[min(log["Alex"])] + [max(log["Alex"])],
#            "Ben":[min(log["Ben"])] + [max(log["Ben"])],
#            "Carla":[min(log["Carla"])] + [max(log["Carla"])]})

current_max = 0
current_min = 100
best_student = "Unknown"
for name, vs in log.items():  # this retrieves key and value for each entry in the dictionary
    mx = vs[1] # why are you comparing the mix with the max of each student? Should this always be j[1]?
    mn = vs[0]
    if mx > current_max:
        current_max, current_min, best_student = mx, mn, name

print("Best student is " + best_student + " his top vote is " + str(current_max) + ". His lowest vote is " + str(current_min))
```

A few comments:

- It is safer to use a loop to run the log update: if, by any chance, you forget to run the update for 1 student manually, you will incur into troubles. The loop "makes sure" this does not happen
- Why, when you run the update of your log dictionary, you update with a list of lists, where the first list always contains the min and the second the max? Can't you update using just a simple list, where the first element is the min, the second the max?

  ```
  log.update({key: [min(vs), max(vs)]})
  ```
- I don't understand why, in your loop, you check what the max is between 2 numbers (I am referring to `m = max(vs[0])`, or `max(i, j)` in your case) where you *already know* the first is the min and the second is the max. If you apply the change described in the previous point, this simply becomes:

  ```
  m = vs[1]
  ```

**NOTE**: I have modified the code so that also the minimum vote for the best student is printed. `current_max` and `current_min` are initialized with low and high values respectively, so that the logic in the loop works (if the 2 numbers are outside the range of possible vote, the first student processes will immediately update both `current_max` and `current_min`). You could have actually initialized `current_max=0`, given that I imagine the vote in this framework cannot be negative

Comment: Why the variable **current_max** is equal to -1?

Comment: Also, I have to find the minimum vote of the best student, so I have to create new variable as **current_min** and also put it to the loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is how one finds the best student:

```
def by_total_grade(name):
    return sum(grades[name])

best_student = max(grades, key=by_total_grade)
```

---

Full example:

```
grades = {
    "Alex": [3, 7, 11, 10, 8],
    "Ben": [6, 12, 4, 9, 9],
    "Сarla": [5, 10, 7, 5, 9],
}

best_student = max(grades, key=lambda k: sum(grades[k]))
best_grades = grades[best_student]

print(
    f"Best student {best_student}, "
    f"max score {max(best_grades)}, "
    f"min score {min(best_grades)}."
)
```

Output:

```
Best student Ben, max score 12, min score 4.
```

Comment: I apologize, but in the title of the question I clearly indicated cycles and dictionaries, I have not yet passed the function lamba and cannot make such a decision

Comment: Lambdas are just unnamed functions.